# How to stop Okhttp Authenticator from being called multiple times?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I have an Authenticator like this

```
@Singleton
class TokenAutheticator @Inject constructor(private val tokenHolder: Lazy<TokenHolder>,private val tokenInterceptor: TokenInterceptor):Authenticator {
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {

        val resp = tokenHolder.get().tokenService.relogin(tokenInterceptor.token).execute()
        println("### res "+resp.code())
        if (resp.code()==200) {
            val body = tokenHolder.get().tokenService.relogin(tokenInterceptor.token).execute()?.body()

            val newToken = body?.token
            println("########## authenticator ########## ")
            val url = route?.address()?.url()?.newBuilder()?.addQueryParameter("token", newToken)?.build()


            return response.request().newBuilder().url(url).build()
        }else{
            return null
        }
    }


}
```

When the `resp.code != 200` the Authenticator is called multiple times. 
I am plugging it in Okhttp like this

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideOkhttp(tokenInterceptor: TokenInterceptor, tokenAutheticator: TokenAutheticator): OkHttpClient {

    val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()

            .authenticator(tokenAutheticator)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
            .build()

    return client
}
```

So what I want to do is have the Authenticator try it only once and if it is able to get a new token then use the new token from now on and if it can't get a new token then exit. But the Authenticator is called multiple times and the API responds with Too many attempts. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. Did you got any solution for it

Answer (score 0):

Only when you return `null`, `Authenticator` will stop getting called (stop retrying authentication).

Since you always return something, when response code is 200, it will get called a few times. Luckily, as far I understand, `Authenticator` detects your endless loop, and breaks out of it eventually.

Basically, you should use `Authenticator` to react to 401 (and similar) response code and only add authorization header in that case.